# Tesponse data must not be correct Tau-prolog.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, prolog, tau-prolog

CODE PL

I am using the prolog interpreter in javascript tau-prolog I see that there are not many references and clear examples of use.

The problem is that it shows the response in an unexpected format

```
   :- use_module(library(lists)).

   % Hechos: Problemas y sus síntomas
   problema(no_enciende, "Verificar la conexión de la fuente de poder y el cable de alimentación.").
   problema(no_arranca_pantalla_azul, "Verificar el estado del disco duro y la memoria RAM.").
   problema(no_se_conecta_a_internet, "Verificar la configuración de la red y la conexión del cable de red.").
   problema(sobrecalentamiento, "Limpiar el polvo y verificar el funcionamiento del ventilador del   procesador.").
   problema(bajo_rendimiento, "Realizar un análisis de malware y optimizar el sistema operativo.").

   % Reglas: Diagnóstico de problemas según los síntomas reportados
   diagnosticar_problema(Sintomas, Solucion) :- problema(Id, Solucion), forall(member(Sintoma,    Sintomas), sintoma_de_problema(Sintoma, Id)).

   % Hechos: Síntomas y su relación con los problemas
   sintoma_de_problema("no enciende", no_enciende).
   sintoma_de_problema("no arranca", no_arranca_pantalla_azul).
   sintoma_de_problema("pantalla azul", no_arranca_pantalla_azul).
   sintoma_de_problema("no se conecta a internet", no_se_conecta_a_internet).
   sintoma_de_problema("sobrecalentamiento", sobrecalentamiento).
   sintoma_de_problema("bajo rendimiento", bajo_rendimiento).

   % agregar nuevos problemas y soluciones
   % problema(lentitud_al_navegar, "Verificar la velocidad de la conexión a internet y limpiar el caché del navegador.").
   % sintoma_de_problema("lentitud al navegar", lentitud_al_navegar).

   % Ejemplo de uso
   % ?- diagnosticar_problema(["no arranca", "pantalla azul"], Solucion).
```

QUERY

```
   session.query(diagnosticar_problema(("no arranca", "pantalla azul"), Solucion)., { 
    ...
```

OUTPUT IS

```
  
    Solucion = [V,e,r,i,f,i,c,a,r, ,l,a, ,c,o,n,e,x,i,ó,n, ,d,e, ,l,a, ,f,u,e,n,t,e, ,d,e, ,p,o,d,e,r, ,y, ,e,l, ,c,a,b,l,e, ,d,e, ,a,l,i,m,e,n,t,a,c,i,ó,n,.]
```

How can I get the result in json format?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfRyP.png)